# Writing a scientific name in an italized phrase?

Tags: academic-writing, scientific-publishing

If I use a scientific name (*Python regius*) in a phrase that is already in italics, should the scientific name then be written normally or underlined? Does anybody know the rule?

Comment: Underlined text in a hanwritten or typewriter manuscript is the equivalent to italics in typeset text. Underlines are not used in typeset text (such as books or magazines), underlines are a substitute for italics where they are not available, for example in handrwiting or on a typewriter. The exception are electronic documents, where underlines have become the standard markup for hyperlinks (for the very reason that they are not otherwise used). **Never** use underlining unless you are writing by hand or on an old typewriter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Underlines are only used to indicate hyperlinks; they should not be used for emphasis.

When you have a block of italicized text, and you have a phrase which would normally be italicized in book or roman text, make your italic phrase book.

> *The ball python, also known as* Python regius, *is a nonvenomous python species found in Africa. This is the smallest of the African pythons and is popular in the pet trade, largely due to its typically docile temperament.*